# Why can't I improve / reject and edit this suggested edit?

Tags: support, bug, review, suggested-edits, spam

I just encountered a [suggested edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/140171) on a post that is possibly spam. Given its score, it's likely to have a couple of pending spam flags already. What is interesting, and a possible [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), is that the options 'Improve edit' and 'Reject and edit' have been disabled. Normally, this only happens when reviewing suggested edits to tag wikis/excerpts (if you have the reputation to [review them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) but not the reputation to [singlehandedly edit them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)). What's going on here?

[image]

Meanwhile, while posting this, the answer *has* been deleted, but I'm sure (up to caching) that I saw this while I could still see the answer on the Q&A page. And the suggested edit is still pending, perhaps waiting for the review task to be invalidated.

The fact that @Xnero could not reproduce it, and *I* can't reproduce it on the [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29203647) mentioned by @Luuklag seems to suggest that this happens for all suggested edits on deleted posts *if you don't have the privilege to view deleted posts* (10k on most sites). I'm still unsure if this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)...

Comment: No repro on the same edit.

Comment: The Improve/Reject & Edit options also go away for me on deleted posts. Maybe that’s what happened here if it was deleted while you were reviewing it.

Comment: I have the same issue on this review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29203647 Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Rt7q.png That might be because it is a tag only edit?

Comment: @Luuklag thanks, I can't reproduce on that edit but I do have 10k+ on SO. Xnero has 10k+ on Travel.SE and I don't, so that definitely seems to make a difference.

Comment: Now you wield that diamond you could slap a [status-review] on this Q tonget an official response ;)

Comment: @Luuklag :) moderators are supposed not to use their powers on their own posts (except for blatantly obvious cases). I'm sure not many people will mind if I make an exception here, but I don't.

Comment: I know, hence the wink eyed emoticon.

Comment: @Glorfindel Does that mean being a moderator doesn't mean you get to post blatantly off-topic questions and then reopen them every time they get closed?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be because the question was deleted and you have less than 10K reputation on Travel.SE. I noticed that even if you have edit privileges, you will not be able to edit any deleted post. Going to the edit link will result in a plain HTML page that reads `This post is deleted and cannot be edited.` However, on the site on which I have the moderator tools privilege, I can edit any deleted, non-locked post just fine. Editing a post single-handedly requires 2K reputation (500 for Beta sites), but editing a deleted post requires 10K reputation (2K for Beta sites).

However, anyone with Edit privileges can review suggested edits, including those on deleted posts. But since they do not have the privileges to edit them themselves, there is no Improve/Reject and Edit option. Only Approve and Reject.

This is supported by the fact that on Stack Overflow, where I have full edit privileges but not access to moderator tools, every time I see only Approve/Reject, the post is already deleted, and that people with 10K+ are not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "edits, including those on deleted posts" — As I understand it, the fact that these aren't removed from the queue automatically is a bug, albeit one that's been around for many years.